# Git SSH permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I can't pull, upload or clone any repositories of my git anymore. I haven't changed anything in the settings and it used to work.

With `ssh -T git@gitlab.server.com` I recieve following answer which looks correct:

```
Welcome to GitLab, @username!
```

But when I try to push, pull, clone or anything, I receive following error message:

```
git@gitlab.server.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I've recreated and configured the SSH keys several times now but I can't find the reason, why this isn't working. Whats weird is that in the official documentation it says, the first command posted above can be used for testing. If this command is working the setup should be working according to the documentation of git.
Do I maybe have to do some configurations on the server site? I've never changed something there and it used to be working.

Please let me know if you need any further debug informations.

Comment: You probably have two ssh agents (and configurations) on your system. When you use `ssh`, it probably is not the same `ssh` when used via `git`..... This happens often on Windows. If you're on Windows, try using git bash.

Comment: Given that it works with plain `ssh` and not with `git push`, this implies that `git push` is not using plain ssh. One reason this happens on Windows is that Git-for-Windows usually comes with its own ssh implementation, in case the one *on* Windows (e.g., Windows Vista) is missing or inadequate. You can set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v` to watch Git run ssh, and/or set it to a particular ssh executable path.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v` it's working.

To set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` in windows open the GIT console and type `GIT_SSH_COMMAND = ssh -v`

Thank you @torek and @sytech for your hints.